# CORS issue from Cyclic API

Tags: javascript, cors, cyclic

I'm a beginner in JS and webdev spent the last days trying to figure out a CORS issue.

I want to fetch poems from my database that is connected with an API through Cyclic.sh

https://send4t-github-io.vercel.app/poems.html

```
async function getPoems() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://extinct-jade-bedclothes.cyclic.app/');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
getPoems();
```

getPoems would get me the text 'Yo' from the above URL

However I'm getting CORS error.

I tried different methods getting rid of CORS and trying to work with my API.

My site is deployed on Vercel so I updated vercel.json

```json
{
"routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",  //I assumed this allows any website to access
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS","FETCH"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Also put CORS requirement into Cyclic's package.json

I recognize the issue might be in Cyclic but their documentation doesn't say anything else. Only says I need to install and require CORS.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See also: https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors